# Prepared statement insertion error with odbc_prepare/execute in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Writing this in PHP, using odbc_prepare and odbc_execute, attempting to insert into MS SQL.

Basically, I am still relativeeely new to all of this but I am familiar with normal (unprepared) MySQL and MSSQL queries. I am trying to use prepared statements now because of their security value. Here is my code:

PHP

```
  //$conn = db connection
  //$dbArray = array with sizeof = 26
  $stmt = odbc_prepare($conn, 'INSERT INTO W2_contact_us_FORM VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,   
  ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
  $success = odbc_execute($stmt, $dbArray);
  if($success) {//success msg} else {//error msg}
```

Also, I feel like there has to be a better way than listing out 26 ?'s but, perhaps there is not? Thank you for your help!

edit -- looking into switching to PDO instead of odbc, so, if you are more familiar with a solution using pdo, I am all ears for that, as PDO appears to be built-in to PHP now as well (hopefully).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use named params which will make it easier to read at least, but you will still need to put all 26 into it. Using PDO you will be able to do something like this:

```
insert into tableName values (:id, :val1, :val2 ....)
```

It's much much easier to read and makes more sense to anyone else reading the code.

Then if you do decide to use the PDO path, you can pass all the params in one fell swoop through an array like this:

```
$prepared->execute(array(':ID' => $ID, ':val1' => $var1, ':val2' => $var2, ...)))
```

Edit: I generally use a few objects in my code, and can do a quick copy and paste if you like:

Classes file:

```
class mysqlDigitalcog
{
    public $con;

    private $userName = "yourDBName";
    private $passWord = "yourPassword";
    private $hostName = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=example"; 
    // Modify this to your connection

    private $isDebug=false;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->con = new PDO ($this->hostName, $this->userName , $this->passWord);
        $this->con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    }

    function __destruct()
    {
        $this->con = null;
    }
}

class myResult
{
    private $mysqlAccess;
    private $prepared;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->mysqlAccess=new mysqlDigitalcog();
    }

    public function loadData1()
    {
        $sql="INSERT INTO W2_contact_us_FORM VALUES (:ID, :val1)";
        $this->prepared = $this->mysqlAccess->con->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
        $this->prepared->execute(array(':ID' => 1, ':val1' => 2))
    }

    public function loadData2($myArray)
    {
        $sql="INSERT INTO W2_contact_us_FORM VALUES (:ID, :val1)";
        $this->prepared = $this->mysqlAccess->con->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
        $this->prepared->execute($myArray)
    }
}
```

Actual Page Code:

```
$myResult=new myResult();
$array=array(":ID" => 3, ":val1" => 4);

$myResult->loadData1();
// Data loaded with 1, 2 as per function.

// or alternately

$myResult->loadData2($array);
// Data loaded with array contencts, here 3, 4
```

Now, we have an object with two functions, one where all the inputs are generated within the function itself, and one where the array of values is being passed to the function externally.

Comment: thank you very much. if you have the time, could you make the code a little more explicit/idiot-proof? is the first line supposed to be `$prepared = '//your query'` and then the second line is operating on that?

Answer (score -2):

Use a for loop to insert the '?'

```
for(int i =0; i<26; i++)
{

}
```